# Java: How to pass arrays to method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I need to calculate the average value of the array and print it out. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public class Weight {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] value = {98, 99, 98, 100, 101, 102, 100, 104, 105,
                    105, 106, 105, 103, 104, 103, 105, 106, 107, 106,
                    105, 105, 104, 103, 102, 102, 101, 100, 102};
    printArray(value);
}

public static void printWeightAVG(int[] value) {
    double average = ((int)value / 28.0);
    System.out.println("The average weight is " + average + " lbs.");
 }
}
```

Comment: Typo: `printArray(value)` should be `printWeightAVG(value)` as well as needing to iterate over the array itself

Comment: Thanks, do you know what I do to use the array to get the average?

Comment: Think of how you'd do it on paper first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void printWeightAVG(int[] value) {

    int sum =0;
    for(int count=0; count<value.length; count++) {
       sum = sum + value[count];
    }
    //double average = ((int)sum/ 28.0); (as in your code)
    double average = sum/value.length; //(better way)
    System.out.println("The average weight is " + average + " lbs.");
}
```

Comment: Ahh thank you. The notes I took on arrays were very confusing. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Also, you don't have to cast sum to int since its already an integer

Answer (score 2):

an array is not a single value, it is a collection of values. You need to iterate through it with a for loop

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
  sum += value[i];
}
System.out.println("average is "+sum/value.length);
```

Basically, what this is saying is "go through every index of the array, then add the value at that index of the array to the sum variable".
if the array is: `[1,4,3]` then `value[1]` will be 4. If you iterate over every value with a variable, you can individually reference everything contained within the array.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to divide an `Array` by a number.  You need to divide the sum of the numbers in `value` by 28, or however many numbers there are, to get the average.

A few notes:

1)  rather than hardcoding the number of elements, you can get it by using `.length`.  So if `sum` is the sum of all of the elements in `value`, you can say `average =`sum`/ value.length`.

2) Be careful with types.  Dividing an `int` by a `float` or a `double` will result in a non-`int` value (which in most cases is what you want, but you need to be careful, particularly if precision is required)